# Is there a way to specify which ssh key should be used for npm install

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, npm

I have a private repo that I want to install in my package.json file.

```
"private-module": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:private/private-module.git"
```

By default npm uses your default private key. I want to be able to specify which ssh key npm should use when running `npm install`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here are a few solutions:

- Add an entry to your `~/.ssh/config`. For example:

  ```
  Host bitbucket.org
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket_key
       IdentitiesOnly yes
  ```
- Use `ssh-agent` and add your key to the agent instance beforehand.
- Use something like [ssh-ident](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident) for choosing ssh agents and identities dynamically based on the current working directory or arguments passed to ssh-ident. As their readme states, you would typically alias ssh-ident to `ssh` so that it's automatically used everywhere.

Comment: So the 3d suggestion seemed promising, but npm seemed to ignore it. I would up using something similar to your first suggestion, based on this https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: Note using a .ppk (Puttygen) file doesn't work for the IdentityFile in the ~/.ssh/config file. It needs to be an OpenSSH file

Comment: #1 worked for me. I had to use puttygen to generate a key and then export it to openssh format.

Comment: Im rather new to all this. Can you explain in more detail. Like what is `~/.ssh/config`. and how do I use `ssh-agent`

Answer (score 4):

After you have made the changes in the first part of  mscdex's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938257/283991) you might need to add the host to the list of known hosts - before the `npm install` command will work.

You can do this by cloning the private repo to another directory:

`git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org:private/private-module.git`

You might be asked if you want to proceed, type `yes` and enter, then bitbucket.org is trusted. Go back to your project directory and retry `npm install`. This is what was needed for mscdex's answer to work for me.

There are other ways of adding trusted hosts, but this does that in addition to verify that you can actually get to the desired private repo.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/123072/ssh-automatically-accept-keys for a solution not requiring to clone the whole repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can apparently do this with

`export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/.ssh/your_private_key'`

Answer (score -3):

Otherwise, you can use your **NPM Token** in your `.npmrc` file:

```
// .npmrc
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${YOUR_NPM_TOKEN}
```

Source: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/118393368555/deploying-with-npm-private-modules

Comment: The question is about choosing a key to be used by `npm install` when installing from a repo. Private registries are irrelevant.