# How to resolve authentication error in npm install?

Tags: git, maven, npm-install, package.json

In my package.json I have private repo called somerepo.git. Now I am running an npm install on a buildserver(bamboo) through maven and getting this error:

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/var/home/ci/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror https://somerepo.git
[ERROR] npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for https://somerepo.git
```

How can I resolve the authentication for the repository?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use private Github repo as npm dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28728665/how-to-use-private-github-repo-as-npm-dependency)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can, you should:

- access the private repo through ssh
- use a deploy or [trusted key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/managing-trusted-keys-800714520.html) that you register to your Git remote hosting server, in order to allow your CI server to access it.
- configure your .ssh/config file in order for npm to use the right key: see "[Is there a way to specify which ssh key should be used for `npm install`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938257/6309)"