# npm install fails HTTP authentication on Linux

Tags: git, npm

I'm attempting to run `npm install git+https://bitbucket.org/User/Repository` on Linux Raspbian 8.0. However, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://bitbucket.org/User/Repository.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! remote: Invalid username or password
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/User/Repository.git/'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

My Bitbucket username and app password *should* be available in both the global and directory git configs:

```
git config user.name "Username"
git config user.password "Password"
git config --global user.name "Username"
git config --global user.password "Password"
```

So, the correct username and password should be available for `npm` to use, but it doesn't seem to use them.

Also, for the avoidance of doubt, I have verified that the username and password are correct by using them with `git` directly.

Any help in resolving this issue would be much appreciated!

**Edit**
Thanks to Matthieu Moy in the comments for pointing out that the config values I was using do not actually have any special meaning for Git.

[According to documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store), username and password combinations can be stored in `~/.git-credentials`. I have done so, in the form `https://Username:Password@bitbucket.org`. However, the same error as above persists. I have verified that the username and app password are otherwise correct. Git simply does not seem to be using them.

Comment: `user.name` is your full name (like John Smith), used when you make a commit. It's not the login name used on remote sites. I don't know where your `user.password` comes from, but it's not a documented Git configuration variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I've been finding the git documentation fairly confusing and I must have got lost somewhere along the way. I'll look into `git-credential-store` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that explicitly specifying the path of `.git-credentials` to `git` resolved the problem. I did so with [the following command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store/1.7.12.1):

```bash
git config --global credential.helper 'store --file=/path/to/.git-credentials'
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this without explicitly defining the credentials in a file?

Comment: @libzz Not that I could find, unfortunately. There may be a way to specify a more secure store, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

@libzz, I can't comment on the accepted answer (I don't have enough reputation), but to answer your question: if you don't want to store your credentials you can use '[cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache)' as the credentials.helper setting.

`git config --global credential.helper cache`

If you supply a username/password to git, it will cache them for 15 minutes.

Thus, prior to your `npm install`, you can do something like a `git pull` on a repo to have git prompt and temporarily cache your credentials. On `npm install` git will be able clone from the same server with your cached credentials.

This eliminates the need to have a file with your credentials stored in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I think that bitbucket doesn't want you to connect from a non-trusted source. For that, you will need a trusted key. The problem has already been resolved: [How to resolve authentication error in npm install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224567/how-to-resolve-authentication-error-in-npm-install)

-- Here is what the person tells you to try--

If you can, you should:

- access the private repo through ssh
- use a deploy or [trusted key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/managing-trusted-keys-800714520.html) that you register to your Git remote hosting server, in order to allow your CI server to access it.
- configure your .ssh/config file in order for npm to use the right key: see "[Is there a way to specify which ssh key should be used for `npm install`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938257/6309)"

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not sure the issue is about a non-trusted source. In a different directory, I successfully ran `git pull` on the remote repository. `git` asked me to input my username and password for Bitbucket, and after doing so, it successfully authenticated.

I did also attempt to pursue the SSH key route, although using Bitbucket Cloud documentation, rather than the one the person you quoted linked. Unfortunately, I ran into issues with that as well. Plus, I wasn't comfortable using it, given that it grants full permissions, whereas app passwords can be permission-limited.